# Swift Array Extension to replace value of index n by the sum of the n-previous values

Tags: arrays, swift, extension-methods, reduce

I am trying to write an extension for Array Types that sums the n-previous indexes in the index n.

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let mySumArray = myArray.sumNIndex()
print(mySumArray)
// returns [1,3,6,10,15]
```

I have tried various approaches which all failed at some point.
For instance, the example hereafter triggers a compile error
"*Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(Int, _)'*":

```
extension Array {
    mutating func indexSum() {
        var tempArray = [Any]()
        for index in 1...self.count - 1 {
        self[index] += self[.prefix(index + 2).reduce(0, +)]
        }
    }
}
```

This other attempt triggers another compile error:
"*Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to two 'Element' operands*"

```
extension Array {
    mutating func indexSum() {
        var tempArray = [Any]()
        for index in 1...self.count - 1 {
        self[index] += self[index - 1]
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea is welcome!
Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT: Many thanks to @Martin and @Carpsen who figured it out in 2 different ways**

***@Martin using map method:***

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric {
    func cumulativeSum() -> [Element] {
        var currentSum: Element = 0
        return map {
            currentSum += $0
            return currentSum
        }
    }
}
```

***@Carpsen using reduce method:***

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric {
    func indexSum() -> [Element] {
        return self.reduce(into: [Element]()) {(acc, element) in
            return acc + [(acc.last ?? 0) + element]
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

myArray.reduce([Int](), {accumulator, element in
    return accumulator + [(accumulator.last ?? 0) + element]
})
//[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

What this `reduce` does is:

- Start  with an empty array
- With each element from `myArray` it calculates its **sum** with the last element in the `accumulator`
- Return the previous array plus the last **sum**

---

Here is a simpler, but longer version:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let newArray = myArray.reduce([Int](), {accumulator, element in
    var tempo = accumulator
    let lastElementFromTheAccumulator = accumulator.last ?? 0
    let currentSum = element + lastElementFromTheAccumulator
    tempo.append(currentSum)
    return tempo
})

print(newArray)  //[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

---

A more efficient solution, as suggested by **Martin R** in the comments, uses [`reduce(into:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2924692-reduce):

```
myArray.reduce(into: [Int]()) { (accumulator, element) in
    accumulator += [(accumulator.last ?? 0) + element]
}
//[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

---

And you could have it as an extension:

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric {
    func indexSum() -> [Element] {
        return self.reduce([Element](), {acc, element in
            return acc + [(acc.last ?? 0) + element]
        })
    }
}

myArray.indexSum()  //[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

---

Here a solution that will work with strings too:

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    func indexSum() -> [String] {
        return self.reduce(into: [String]()) {(accumulator, element) in
            accumulator += [(accumulator.last ?? "") + element]
        }
    }
}

["a", "b", "c", "d"].indexSum() //["a", "ab", "abc", "abcd"]
```

If you'd like to have a separator between the elements of the initial array elements, you could use this extension:

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    func indexSum(withSparator: String) -> [String] {
        return self.reduce(into: [String]()) {(accumulator, element) in
            var previousString = ""
            if let last = accumulator.last {
                previousString = last + " "
            }
            accumulator += [previousString +  element]
        }
    }
}

["a", "b", "c", "d"].indexSum(withSparator: " ") //["a", "a b", "a b c", "a b c d"]
```

Comment: Thanks Carpsen! It works, but would you mind explaining it a bit further so I can better understand how you wrote/found this closure please?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Carpsen! I am just starting with Swift so I read fine the longer version (thanks!!) but I still have troubles jumping from the longer version to the shorter. I need to figure out how come you return an Array and not the value in the short version. Besides would you know how to make it work with Strings? Many, many thanks!

Comment: This creates a lot of intermediate arrays. You should at least use `reduce(into:)`

Comment: @Chris `accumulator` is an array, so  `accumulator + [(accumulator.last ?? 0) + element]` is an array two. You get a longer array by adding two arrays using `+`

Comment: @MartinR Thank you, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: @Chris I'll update the answer with a general solution as soon as possible

Comment: @Chris I've updated the answer for an array of strings

Comment: @Carpsen @Martin, you're awesome guys! Thanks a ton! It also gives me food for thoughts, small things like `reduce(into)` takes me back to square one lol

Comment: @MartinR That depends entirely on the characteristics of the expected inputs. That's not a statement that can be made categorically, especially in response to an example of size `n = 5`.

Comment: @WayneBurkett: Fair point. I'll reformulate it: `reduce(into:)` can be used to reduce(!) the number of intermediate arrays (and that's what it was made for: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0171-reduce-with-inout.md)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the addition operator `+` is not defined for elements
of arbitrary arrays. You need to restrict the extension method, e.g. to
arrays of `Numeric` elements.

Also there is no need to use `Any`.

Here is a possible implementation as a non-mutating method:

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric {
    func cumulativeSum() -> [Element] {
        var currentSum: Element = 0
        return map {
            currentSum += $0
            return currentSum
        }
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
let intArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(intArray.cumulativeSum()) // [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]

let floatArray = [1.0, 2.5, 3.25]
print(floatArray.cumulativeSum()) [1.0, 3.5, 6.75]
```

---

In a similar fashion we can “cumulatively join” the elements of a 
string array. `enumerated()` is now used to provide the current element
index together with the element, and that is used to decide whether to
insert the separator or not:

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    func cumulativeJoin(separator: String) -> [Element] {
        var currentJoin = ""
        return enumerated().map { (offset, elem) in
            if offset > 0 { currentJoin.append(separator) }
            currentJoin.append(elem)
            return currentJoin
        }
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
let stringArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(stringArray.cumulativeJoin()) // ["a", "ab", "abc"]
print(stringArray.cumulativeJoin(separator: ":")) // ["a", "a:b", "a:b:c"]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time on this Martin. Your remarks make sense, and I thought I had to use a Protocol. However, 2 things: (1) the code does compile but returns the same array [1,2,3,4,5] and (2) I'd like the code to work on Strings as well, hence the Numeric Protocol might be too restrictive. Thanks again!!!

Comment: For `let intArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` , `print(intArray.cumulativeSum())` returns [1,2,3,4,5] instead of [1,2,6,10,15]

Comment: @Chris: Oops. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin! It works like a charm! I think I understand the idea: you increment the currentSum property with the index value thanks to the map method, but what I don't really understand is the successive `returns` on the one hand and why you did not write self.map instead of map on the other hand. Last but not least, I'd like it to work with Strings as well.

Comment: @Chris: `map()` defaults to `self.map()` (as do all instance methods). `map()` calls the closure with each array element in turn, and returns the array with the results. – What should `["a","b"].cumulativeSum()` return?

Comment: Indeed you are right about the implicit `self.map()` ! I am just not enough familiar with the code yet!  `["a","b"].cumulativeSum()` throws an compile error *Type of expression is ambiguous without more context*. PS: I have edited the original post to show both @Carpsen and you figured it out and I cannot validate 2 answers.

Comment: @Chris: It is still unclear to me how you *define* the cumulative sum of a string array `["a","b"]`. What do you *want* the result to be?

Comment: it isn't common indeed :) but ideally `["a","b",c"]` would return `["a","a b","a b c"]` using a separator which can be "", " ", /n...

Comment: Thanks @Martin! The closure is neat and clear thanks to your explanations. It helps me better understand how map, reduce and enumerated work which are fundamental for collections.